# How do I reference subdocument array's ObjectId to another model

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, objectid

```
usermodel:
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a2622b0004be35f4baf70e3"),
"username": "testuser",
"bankdetails" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a294146015da72db1560326"),            
            "bankname" : "bankofamerica"
        }
]
}


samplemodel:
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a41f785416d0d3d93794ca9"),   
    "bankid" : ObjectId("5a294146015da72db1560326"),
}


samplemodel.find().populate('bankid').exec(function(err,resData){
    res.json(resData);
});
```

I have used the above code but not working this code...please give some solution to solve this problem.....

Comment: can you explain a bit more on what you are trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 1):

You have to update the Schema, Create a separate schema for banks. and pass into "bankdetails" as embedded document, To get result from sample model you need to pass Reference of Bank Schema. Example:

```
var BankSchema = new Schema({
   bankname:{ type: String}
});

var Bank = mongoose.model('Bank', BankSchema); 

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  username:{ type: String},
  bankdetails:[BankSchema],
});

var SampleSchema = new Schema({
  sameple_string:{ type: String},
    bankid:{
      type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref:'Bank'
    },
});
```